# Good input validation loop using cin - C++

Tags: c++, loops, validation

I'm in my second OOP class, and my first class was taught in C#, so I'm new to C++ and currently I am practicing input validation using cin. So here's my question:

Is this loop I constructed a pretty good way of validating input? Or is there a more common/accepted way of doing it?

Thanks!

Code:

```
int taxableIncome;
int error;

// input validation loop
do
{
    error = 0;
    cout << "Please enter in your taxable income: ";
    cin >> taxableIncome;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
        error = 1;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    }
}while(error == 1);
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of turning on exceptions for iostreams.  I/O errors aren't exceptional enough, in that errors are often very likely.  I prefer only to use exceptions for less frequent error conditions.

The code isn't bad, but skipping 80 characters is a bit arbitrary, and the error variable isn't necessary if you fiddle with the loop (and should be `bool` if you keep it).  You can put the read from `cin` directly into an `if`, which is perhaps more of a Perl idiom.

Here's my take:

```
int taxableIncome;

for (;;) {
    cout << "Please enter in your taxable income: ";
    if (cin >> taxableIncome) {
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Apart from only skipping 80 characters, these are only minor quibbles, and are more a matter of preferred style.

Comment: Thanks, this is more along the lines of what I was looking for. Much appreciated. One question though, what is the for loop condition (;;)? Don't understand that.

Comment: @Alex - `foo(;;)` means loop forever, just like `while(1)`.  If you don't want your loop to truly loop forever, you need a `break` somewhere inside to terminate the loop.

Comment: I'd typically have while(!eof(stdin)) in such a case, to avoid the code go crazy if the input is lost... or will that throw an exception here ?

Answer (score 6):

```
int taxableIncome;
string strInput = "";
cout << "Please enter in your taxable income:\n";

while (true) 
{
    getline(cin, strInput);

    // This code converts from string to number safely.
    stringstream myStream(strInput);
    if ( (myStream >> taxableIncome) )
        break;
    cout << "Invalid input, please try again" << endl;
}
```

So you see I use string for input and then convert that to an integer. This way, someone could type enter, 'mickey mouse' or whatever and it will still respond.
Also #include `<string>` and `<sstream>`

Comment: `while (true) { getline(cin, strInput); ... }` should be `while (getline(cin, strInput)) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

One minor quibble is that the error helper variable is completely redundant and is not needed:

```
do
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter in your taxable income: ";
    cin >> taxableIncome;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    }
}while(cin.fail());
```

Comment: You should not be calling `cin.clear()` before reading from `cin`. You should call `cin.clear()` only if reading actually fails. IOW, move it inside your `if` block before calling `cin.ignore()`. As for `ignore()` itself, you should use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead of hard-coding `80`.

Answer (score 2):

Might you not consider try/catch, just to get you used to the concept of exception handling?

If not, why not use a boolean, instead of 0 and 1? Get into the habit of using variables of the correct type (and of creating types where needed)

Cin.fail() is also discussed at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/

In fact, in many places ...

http://www.google.com.sg/#hl=en&source=hp&q=c%2B%2B+tutorial&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=c%2B%2B+tutorial

you might study some of those and try to follow the explanations of why things should be done a certain way.

But, sooner or later, you ought to understand exceptions...