# Trying to use a while statement to validate user input C++

Tags: c++, validation

I am new to C++ and am in a class.  I am trying to finish the first project and so far I have everything working correctly, however, I need the user to input a number to select their level, and would like to validate that it is a number, and that the number isn't too large.

```
while(levelChoose > 10 || isalpha(levelChoose))
{
    cout << "That is not a valid level" << endl;
    cout << "Choose another level:";
    cin >> levelChoose;
}
```

That is the loop I made, and it sometimes works.  If I type in 11 it prints the error, and lets me choose another level.  However if the number is large, or is any alpha character it floods the screen with the couts, and the loop won't end, and I have to force exit.  Why does it sometimes stop at the cin and wait for user input, and sometimes not?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What type is the levelChoose variable?

Comment: It is usually a good idea to provide a compilable example of the code that does not work. That we we have everything we need to diagnose the problem without having to ask a laod of extra questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an annoying problem with cin (and istreams in general).  cin is type safe so if you give it the wrong type it will fail.  As you said a really large number or non-number input it gets stuck in an infinite loop.  This is because those are incompatible with whatever type levelChoose may be.  cin fails but the buffer is still filled with what you typed so cin keeps trying to read it.  You end up in an infinite loop.

To fix this, you need to clear the fail bit and ignore all the characters in the buffer.  The code below should do this (although I haven't tested it):

```
while(levelChoose > 10 || isalpha(levelChoose))
{
    cout << "That is not a valid level" << endl;
    cout << "Choose another level:";
    if(!(cin >> levelChoose))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Edit: numeric_limits<> is located in the limits include:

```
#include<limits>
```

Comment: The compiler says numeric_limits has not been defined, although I have included iostream, and am using namespace std.

Comment: Sorry!  I should have mentioned that you'll need to #include<limits>

Comment: I ended up doing this
while(levelChoose > numLevels || isalpha(levelChoose))
    {
        cout << "That is not a valid level" << endl;
        cout << "Choose another level:";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin >> levelChoose;
    } using what you said, it worked perfectly!  I had to get rid of the if(!cin) part, because sometimes it would require 2 numbers before the error actually printed out.  But that is perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: As a side note, this works for removing alpha, but if the number is too large, it just exits the loop and proceeds to the next statement.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems likely (nearly certain) that `levelChose` is some sort of numeric type, probably an integer.

When you use `operator>>` to read a number, anything that couldn't be part of a number (e.g., most letters) will be left in the input buffer. What's happening is that you're trying to read the number, it's failing and leaving the non-digit in the buffer, printing out an error message, then trying to read exactly the same non-digit from the buffer again.

Generally, when an input like this fails, you want to do something like ignoring everything in the input buffer up to the next new-line.

Answer (score 0):

levelChoose appears to be an integer type of some form (int, long, whatever).

It's not valid to input a character into an integer directly like that. The input fails, but leaves the character in the incoming buffer, so it's still there when the loop comes around again.

Here's a related question: [Good input validation loop using cin - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c)

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the part `while(levelChoose > 10`..... This does not restrict level to less than 10 (assuming greater than 10 is a large number in your context). Instead it *probably* should be `while(levelChoose < 10...`

To check that an expression is not too large, the following could be a possibility to validate (brain compiled code!!)

```
const unsigned int MAX = 1000;

unsigned int x;
cin >> x;

while(x < MAX){}
```

Comment: The logic was correct. He just didn't realise that `cin` needs to be flushed between iterations, otherwise there might be junk values in the buffer.