# Catching strings while using cin for integer input

Tags: c++, cin

I've seen similar posts to this all around google/stackoverflow. However, I can't find one close enough to my scenario and I don't know C/C++ well enough to port other suggestions over to my methods. Perhaps that's a sign in and of itself...

Regardless, here is my code:

```
while (true)
{
    print("\nSend message, enter command, or \"9\" for help.\n");

    if (cin >> input)
    {
        if (input == TERMINAL_HELP)
        {
            //Some help code.
        }
        else if (input == TERMINAL_EXIT)
        {
            //Some exit code.
        }
        else if (input < 4 && input >= 0)
        {
            // Some processing code.
        }
        else
        {
            print("Please enter a valid message.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Please enter a valid message.");
    }
}
```

The catches works fine for single characters or integers outside of the range [0-4]. But when I put a string in, it gets very weird. It keeps looping through itself infinitely. However after the first time this should be impossible because I do not press enter. It continues through as if it is receiving a blank infinitely.

If you have any suggestions or can point me in the direction of fixing my issue I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

NOTE:

I was trying to follow this, and it worked to some extent. (I got the cin >> input within the if statement idea from this link...) But it does not work to block strings from making the program loop oddly.

[Good input validation loop using cin - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c)

Comment: There *are* hundreds of duplicates of this, you just have to read carefully through the explanations. Or just read the manual for iostreams.

Comment: So this is probably not worth leaving up?

Comment: See how it pans out. Maybe you'll get a better response here than any of the existing ones... (but do also search this site and read language referencs to see if you can figure it out yourself). A good Baby's First Test of your own understanding is to ask yourself what happens if the input file is closed, as in `echo "" | ./a.out`.

Comment: Sounds good. I will. I posted a stack question I was using to make some amends to my code above. As I said, it was helpful, but didn't stop my issue with strings.

Comment: @MooingDuck. I referenced that link in my post. I also explained why that question does not answer mine.

Comment: @phileaton: You explained, but you were wrong.  The code in the first answer does indeed answer this question.  Namely, look at what he does in the else block of `if(cin>>input)` compared to what you do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to get you started with something..

Key points:

- the iostreams (including cin) have something called "error flags"
- when error occurs, the stream can be configured to either *) raise an exception *) skip next operations
- the default configuration is .. to not throw and skip further operations

This means, that if you do:

```
cin >> integer1;
cin >> integer2; // *!
cin >> integer3; // !
cin >> integer4; // !
```

and if the user provides a non-integer at the line marked with (*), then at this point of time the cin will enter an error state and operations marked with (!) **will be skipped**.

Most probably this is why you get weird behavior like infinite read loops etc.

To handle this:

- either configure the stream to throw exceptions - and catch them
- or check error state after every few reads - and handle them

i.e.

```
cin >> integer1; if(cin.fail()) { cout << "wtf?!"; cin.clear(); .. return; }
cin >> integer2; if(cin.fail()) { cout << "wtf?!"; cin.clear(); .. return; }
cin >> integer3; if(cin.fail()) { cout << "wtf?!"; cin.clear(); .. return; }
cin >> integer4; if(cin.fail()) { cout << "wtf?!"; cin.clear(); .. return; }
```

`cin.reset` clears error flags and allows further operation on the stream. However, all the trash-data **will still linger** in the stream. So, there's no point in trying to read further. After cin.reset you should somehow remove that bad-data and recover from the situation. I've marked the places with "..", because there are many ways to do it.

For example, cin.ignore..

Now please refer to all-that-other posts :) I'm sure that you will now quickly find a solution

EDIT: aargh.. sorry, I've floated too far from the actual answer.. What you actually wanted is not a good-errorhandling, but something similar to what **sehe** wrote: instead of reading an integers, you should read a "string" and then inspect it, and then either re-parse them as integers or treat as string-data..

Comment: You're thinking `cin.clear()`, not `reset()` (that doesn't exist). You'll also want to ignore some of the input. And no need to be that verbose, just say `if (!(cin >> integer1)) { cout << "wtf"; }`.

Comment: as for the ! versus fail(), there were some issues with that.. I dont remeber precisely, but it was related to the `void* operator` being equivalent to `good` which was not equal to `!fail` and something with `eof` handling... maybe it was changed in C11, I dont remember now really..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly fixed up minimal example (that compiles...) showing how you could do the stuff you try around

```
 msg = input + '0';
```

Namely:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << input;
auto msg = oss.str();
```

Or, using even more c++11 features (if your compiler has them):

```
auto msg = to_string(input);
```

The rest without further comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int const TERMINAL_EXIT = 9;
int const TERMINAL_HELP = 8;

static int devHandle = 0;

void print(char const*const  msg) { cout << msg; }

void send(int, std::string const&) {} // TODO
void receive(int, std::string&)    {} // TODO
void help_routine() {} // TODO

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        print("\nSend message, enter command, or \"9\" for help.\n");
        // Read in message to send to DigiSpark.

        long input;
        if (cin >> input)
        {
            if (input == TERMINAL_HELP)
            {
                help_routine();
            }
            else if (input == TERMINAL_EXIT)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (input < 4 && input >= 0)
            {
#ifdef HAVE_CXX11
                std::string msg = to_string(input);
#else
                std::ostringstream oss;
                oss << input;
                std::string msg = oss.str();
#endif
                // Send mimicking command line arguments.
                send(devHandle, msg);
                cout << "\nSent message: " << msg << endl;
                print("Receiving message...\n");

                receive(devHandle, msg);

                while (!msg.empty())
                {
                    receive(devHandle, msg);
                }

                cout << "Received message: " << msg << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                print("Please enter a valid message.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("Please enter a valid message.");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How much of that requires C++11? I am not able to use that.

Comment: Tell me instead, what _are_ you able to use? (i.e. what _are_ you using)?

Comment: I believe it is C++98.

Comment: @phileaton anyways, no longer needs any c++11. I'm not saying I fixed much, just made it compile and hopefully gives you some pointers.

Comment: I appreciate it. It is a good method. I'm just trying to avoid the double parsing. But maybe that is the better choice.