# Is there a way to detect if an integer that is inputted is a string?

Tags: c++

I made a basic calculator. Everything works as intended, the only problem being is that when num1 or num2 are inputted as a string/letter, everything just breaks and causes an endless loop. Is there a way to detect if an integer/double is inputted as a string? If there is, maybe I can make this calculator a little bit better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double num1;
    double num2;
    string op;
    string rep;
    bool again1 = true;
    bool again = true;

    while(again == true)
    {
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Operation: ";
    cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter second number: ";
    cin >> num2;

    again = false;
    again1 = true;

    if(op == "+" || op == "add")
    {
        cout << num1 << "+" << num2 << " = " << num1+num2 << endl;
    } else if(op == "-"){
        cout << num1 << "-" << num2 << " = " << num1-num2 << endl;
    } else if(op == "*" || op == "x"){
        cout << num1 << "x" << num2 << " = " << num1*num2 << endl;
    } else if(op == "/"){
        if(num2 == 0){
            cout << "(SYNTAX ERROR)";
        } else {
        cout << num1 << "/" << num2 << " = " << num1/num2 << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;


    while(again1 == true){
    again1 = false;
    cout << "Would you like to try again? Y/N: ";
    cin >> rep;
    if(rep == "Y" || rep == "y")
    {
        again = true;
        cout << "Very well!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if(rep == "N" || rep == "n")
    {
        again = false;
        cout << "Ok, see you later!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid Answer" << endl;
        again1 = true;
        }
    }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578549/catching-strings-while-using-cin-for-integer-input

Answer (score 0):

You can take input in strings, and then you can convert those strings to integer or another data type using any appropriate method according to your need [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/).

If conversion is not possible it may throw an `invalid_argument` exception that you can catch and ask user to input valid number.