# When the reading of an int ends in C++

Tags: c++, types, cin

could you explain me when the reading of an int in C++ is terminated ? Is it terminated with withespace just as when we read into a string type object ?

Comment: Could you enhance this question with a sample showing your particular observations, and what didn't work for you please?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c

Answer (score 0):

If you have input line as space separated list like say 2 43 56, you need to read this as three integers as:

```
std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

where

```
int a, b, c;
```

Otherwise you need use cin.getline as in:

```
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

and then parse, as required