# Reading data into struct with istringstream

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a struct with five data members:

```
struct Info {
    std::string name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string school;
    int age;
    int dob;
}
```

And a string in the format: Joe Bob University 18 050797 where each field represents something I want to read into each member of the struct. I want to know for sure, that each data member in the struct was read in a value, and that the read did not fail. Is there an elegant way of accomplishing this?

```
void fill_info(const std::string &line, Info *fields) {
    istringstream ss(line);
    ss >> fields->name;
    ss >> fields->last_name;
    ss >> fields->school;
    ss >> fields->age;
    ss >> fields->dob;
}
```

Comment: `if (ss >> fields->name >> fields->last_name >> ...) { life is good }`

Comment: you can consider cereal library: http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the insertion in one line and test the stream

```
if(!(ss >> fields->name >> fields->last_name >>\
     fields->school >> fields->age >> fields->dob))
    std::cout << "error reading the data";
```

If you want to see exactly which field failed, you can test each individual insertion. Then, [you can validate the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c).