# cin >> int given a string assigns int to 0

Tags: c++, cin

The issue that I'm having is that if you input any string the cin will assign the int to 0. An interesting finding is that if you later take cin to a string you get the entire string you put in for the int. cin.fail() always returns true for some reason, even with cin.ignore(), etc and if( cin >> startingPosition ) also always returns true. So, how do I get it to catch an even recognize that it's a string and not an int? As in, how do I have it loop again if it is a string?

```
int getUserPosition(bool volatileCall = false) {
    cout << "Which slot do you want to drop the chip in (0-8)? " << endl;
    int startingPosition;
    cin >> startingPosition;
    while (startingPosition >= WIDTH || startingPosition < 0) {
    cout << "Invalid slot." << endl << endl;

        if (volatileCall) {
            return -1;
        }
        cout << "Which slot do you want to drop the chip in (0-8)? " << endl;
        cin >> startingPosition;
        cout << startingPosition << endl;

    }
    return startingPosition;
}
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And please elaborate on your question, or rather *ask* us a question.

Comment: *"The issue that I'm having is that if you input any string the cin will assign the int to 0."* I don't see how that's an issue... what else should it do with the invalid input?

Comment: @Blaze An alternative could be leaving the int to the previous value, or reporting error.

Comment: That's right. As for the error, `>>` returns `false` on error. There's a nice answer on validating streaming integers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076144/10411602

Comment: A small terminology issue: assignment goes in the other direction, from value to object; it assigns 0 to the int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must save result from cin

`isNumber = (cin >> startPosition);`

the whole code will look like

```
int getUserPosition(bool volatileCall = false) {
    cout << "Which slot do you want to drop the chip in (0-8)? " << endl;
    int startingPosition;
    bool isNumber = (cin >> startingPosition);
    while(isNumber && (startingPosition >= WIDTH || startingPosition < 0)) {
        cout << "Invalid slot." << endl << endl;
        if (volatileCall) {
            return -1;
        }
        cout << "Which slot do you want to drop the chip in (0-8)? " << endl;
        isNumber = (cin >> startingPosition);
        cout << startingPosition << endl;
    }
    return startingPosition;
}
```

Comment: This won't work at all. `bool isNumber = (cin >> startingPosition);` is invalid since C++11, the test in the `while` is reversed, and you need to clear the state of `cin` to recover from an error.

Comment: @n.m. you are right. I don't test it in C++11.. I will fix this later