# C++ infinite for loop i cant stop it

Tags: c++, c++11

So i have this code to ask a user input which is numbers and put it to vector and i succesfully do it BUT when a user accidentally put a letter on it or any character it will go for a infinite for loop just a beginner :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char letter{}; 
    int howmany {};
    vector <int> vector {};
    cout << "How many elements inside list? ";
    cin >> many;
    for (int i{1}; i <= howmany;i++){
        int arr {};
        cout << "Please enter number"<<endl;
        cin >> arr;
        vector.push_back(arr);
```

Comment: How about validating your input before you start your for loop?

Comment: The variable is called `howmany` yet you do `cin >> many` - I don't think this code even compiles.

Comment: What you want is input validation. You could take some inspiration from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c

Comment: Yeah i resolve it by using cin.fail cin.clear cin.ignore but i change my for loop into while loop so that i can use it.

Comment: @CherryDT yeah but it just happens when i type it here it is correct on my code it just typo error when i type it here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good input validation loop using cin - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c)

Comment: even `^C` fails? bulletproof cycle

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   char letter{}; 
   int howmany {};
   vector <int> vector {};
   cout << "How many elements inside list? ";
   cin >> howmany;
   for (int i=1; i <= howmany;i++){
      int arr {};
      cout << "Please enter number"<<endl;
      cin >> arr;
      vector.push_back(arr);
   }
}
```

cin >> howmany; //LINE 9