# if and else user verification issue

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

```
int main()
{
    int account_or_not;
    account obj;
    menu menu_obj;

    cout << "Do you have an account? 1 for yes or 2 for no " << endl;
    cin >> account_or_not;


    if (account_or_not == 1)
    {
        menu_obj.user_menu();
    }
    else if (account_or_not == 2)
    {
        obj.create_account();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You entered a value other than 1 or 2 please try again "<< endl;
        cin >> account_or_not;
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

This is what is in the main of my code, and im not sure if I am being dumb, but I have tried a switch case and if else and in the else (or default for switch) when I check what the user has entered was wrong and prompt them to enter it again the program ends when they enter the correct value. E.g if 3 was entered it would tell the user to try again, then when 1 or 2 is entered the program ends. Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: you should read about while loops

Comment: you said about switch statement but there is no switch in your code

Comment: This is exactly what you programmed. When the user input is, say, 0, you print "You entered..." and read `account_or_not`, then exit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that you are not looping until the user enters the right input. You can use do-while loop to do so!

Refer [this](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/do-while-statements/) for more info on do-while loops in C++.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let's go in tiny steps. First, let's ask the user only once to correct their input and let's further assume that the user must get it right on the second attempt. You should first check for valid input and then use it, not the other way around:

```
cin >> account_or_not;
if (account_or_not != 1 && account_or_not != 2) 
{
    cout << "You entered a value other than 1 or 2 please try again "<< endl;
    cin >> account_or_not;
}

// assume input is now valid...
if (account_or_not == 1)
{
    menu_obj.user_menu();
}
else if (account_or_not == 2)
{
    obj.create_account();
}
```

This will only ask for corrected input once. If you want to keep asking until the user entered correct input you can use a loop:

```
cin >> account_or_not;
while (account_or_not != 1 && account_or_not != 2) 
{
    cout << "You entered a value other than 1 or 2 please try again "<< endl;
    cin >> account_or_not;
}

// assume input is now valid...
if (account_or_not == 1)
{
    menu_obj.user_menu();
}
else if (account_or_not == 2)
{
    obj.create_account();
}
```

Now this asks for valid input repedeatly until the user enters `1` or `2`. However, it does not correctly handle the case of the user entering `foo` or `user input is the worst that can happen to a program`. If the user input cannot be parsed as an `int` then `std::cin` is in an error state that you need to recover from before reading more. I said I want to make tiny steps, and I don't have to repeat what has been written elsewhere, so I refer you to this Q&A for further reading: [Good input validation loop using cin - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2075898/4117728).

Comment: right thank you this worked perfectly, I will keep in mind the format of this for other times, I get it now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example using while loop. If the user enter 1 or 2 then do some work in the respective condition block and then `break` out of the while loop. On the other hand if the user enters 3 then ask the user for input again.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int account_or_not;
    //account obj;
    //menu menu_obj;

    std::cout << "Do you have an account? 1 for yes or 2 for no " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> account_or_not;


    while(true)
    {
    if (account_or_not == 1)
    {
       // menu_obj.user_menu();
       std::cout<<"inside 1"<<std::endl;
       //do something and then break
       break;
    }
    else if (account_or_not == 2)
    {
        //obj.create_account();
        std::cout<<"inside 2"<<std::endl;
        //do something and then break
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "You entered a value other than 1 or 2 please try again "<< std::endl;
        std::cin >> account_or_not;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This does what you want. Try it out with different input like 1,2 or 3.